# c# Contains multiple words not together

Tags: c#, contains

```
   if (r.Contains("Word1" + "Word2"))
```

This code checks if "Word1" and "Word2" are in the string together e.g. nothing in between them but how does one check if the string contains those two words regardless of order or any other words in between them?

e.g.
Returns true if string is

```
    Word1Word2
```

Returns false

```
    Word1 Text Word2
```

Comment: did you try Regex pattern matching?

Comment: I seriously doubt `r.Contains("Word1" + "Word2")` will match `Word1 Word2` as it will try to find  `Word1Word2`.

Comment: Yes I tried that, but the solution is much simpler :) See below

Comment: @SimonBelanger Sorry mistake, edited!

Comment: Then its simple don't need pattern matching or index checks and more conditions. just r.Contains ("Word1" + "Word2")

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just verify that each word is contained on `r`.

```
if (r.Contains("Word1") && r.Contains("Word2"))
```

This code checks for the existence of `"Word1"` **AND** `"Word2"` inside the original string, regardless its relative position inside the string.

**Edit:**

As @Alexei Levenkov (+1) note on his comment, the same solution can be reached using `IndexOf` method.

```
if (r.IndexOf("Word1", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1 
    && r.IndexOf("Word2", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1))
```

Comment: But this will not prove  Word1 Text Word2 as false

Comment: @bjoshi OP says that returning `false` on it is a problem with his original solution.

Comment: @bjoshi He want's `Word1 Text Word2` as `true` (it wasn't that obvious to me too).

Comment: I think the expectations have changed multiple times, now is Returns true if string is Word1Word2
Returns false Word1 Text Word2. So the r.Contains ("Word1" + "Word2") itself will work right

Comment: @bjoshi I think that OP wants to show with these examples the behavior of his/her original code, not the expected results.

Comment: Ahh sorry for the comments then

Comment: +1. Note that it is often better to use `IndexOf` as you can specify `IgnoreCase` (unlike `Contains`).

Answer (score 10):

Check that each word is contained within the string:

```
if (r.Contains("Word1") && r.Contains("Word2")))
```

If this is something you do often, you can improve readability (IMO) and conciseness by making an extension method:

```
public static bool ContainsAll(this string source, params string[] values)
{
    return values.All(x => source.Contains(x));
}
```

Used like:

```
"Word1 Text Word2".ContainsAll("Word1", "Word2") // true
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use an `&&` operator for that:

```
if (r.Contains("Word1") &&  r.Contains("Word2"))
```

Note that this would check that both words are there in any order. If you must ensure that the first word precedes the second, get indexes of each word, and check that the index of the first word is lower than the index of the second one:

```
var ind1 = r.IndexOf("Word1");
var ind2 = r.IndexOf("Word2");
if (ind1 >= 0 && ind2 > ind1) {
    ...
}
```